# How to find why an application uses X11 on OSX?

Tags: macos, boost, opencv, x11

I have an application that I built myself. However, it says it needs X11 although it shouldn't . How can I easily (without expanding ldd over and over) figure out which dependency caused X11?

If it helps, here is the output of otool -L:

```
libopencv_core.2.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.3.0, current version 2.3.1)
libopencv_imgproc.2.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.3.0, current version 2.3.1)
libopencv_features2d.2.3.dylib (compatibility version 2.3.0, current version 2.3.1)
/opt/local/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version     0.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/opt/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.16.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

thanks and best wishes

**UPDATE**
it is a unit testing executable for a computer vision module. And it is written in C++, built using cmake.

Comment: What application is it, and how did you build it? Did you go thru some `configure` step? How ??

Comment: probably your problem is that you think that checking on one executable only can be enough to retrieve the list of the all related libraries; the problem is that a single library can be linked against other libraries, just like a dynamic executable, so you also need to check all the libraries linked to your original executable to find out if the X11 lib is in use.

Comment: the problem is this tree has exponentially many dependencies on how many layers I check. It doesn't sound feasible to do so. I am wondering whether there is a better way to do this and hoping somebody seems something suspicious in my list.

Comment: There seems to be a fair bit of chatter about opencv and x11. http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/40304